# Camera API is deprecated in Zxing library

Tags: android, zxing, camera-api

When I checked my Zxing library, Camera API is deprecated. I am curious that whether the API is usable or not. If it is not usable, do i need to use Camera API 2 instead of Camera API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the original `android.hardware.Camera` API is usable, at least through the now-current API Level 25.